# Android - how to disable my application getting casted to SmartTv

Tags: android, google-cast

My App is a Video streaming app and there are some content license agreements which we need to follow. So i have to restrict Application video only to the device display. i dont want my app to be shown on the TV while my device screen is mirrored on the smart TV. Is there any way we can block the Screen Mirroring/Cast at View/Fragmanet/Activity/Application Level?

Comment: [Screen Casting](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6059461?hl=en-IN) is something you many not be able to use it like the way you say here, but you can restrict the app, that when other app, overlays it, it will restrict OR will close casting.

Comment: Is this issue resolved, I need urgent help on this